# My JavaScript slideshow goes forward an image and then back after selecting previous

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I am creating a JavaScript slideshow. It works for the most part. However, when toggling back after moving forward many images it goes forward one image, and then will go back. It will also do this when going forward an image aver toggling back for a while. I do not know if this post makes much sense as it is a difficult question to phrase.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("next");
const previousBtn = document.querySelector("previous");
const image = document.getElementById("slideShow");

let imageNumber = 0;

console.log(image.src, imageNumber);

const slideForward = function () {
  image.src = `slide-${imageNumber++}.PNG`;
  console.log(image.src, imageNumber);

  if (imageNumber > slideArray.length - 1) {
    imageNumber = 1;
  }
};

const slideBack = function () {
  image.src = `slide-${imageNumber--}.PNG`;
  console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
  if (imageNumber < 0) {
    imageNumber = slideArray.length - 1;
  }
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (q) {
  if (q.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    slideBack();
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (q) {
  if (q.key === "ArrowRight") {
    slideForward();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Days+One&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <body  id="picturesStyle" >

    
    <nav class="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="books.html">Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

   
    <img width="600" id="slideShow" src="PleaseWork.png" alt="">
    <button class="next" onclick="slideForward()">Next</button>
    <button class="previous" onclick="slideBack()">Previous</button>


    </main>
    <title>SlideShow</title>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you need two "keydown" events. Move if (q.key === "ArrowRight") { slideForward();} and if (q.key === "ArrowLeft") { slideBack(); } into the same event

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think the reason you are experiencing the issue caused by the lines

`` image.src = `slide-${imageNumber++}.PNG`; ``

`` image.src = `slide-${imageNumber--}.PNG`; ``

and if checks and the starting index of the array.

I would do like this

```
const slideForward = function () {
  if (++imageNumber >= slideArray.length) { //Increase the value first and check it if it is out of range
    imageNumber = 0; //indexes don't start from 1. They start from 0
  }

  image.src = `slide-${imageNumber}.PNG`; 
  console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
};
```

Same logic applies for slideBack function

```
const slideBack = function () {
   if (--imageNumber <= 0) { //Decrease the value first and check it if it is out of range
    imageNumber = slideArray.length - 1;
  }

  image.src = `slide-${imageNumber}.PNG`;
  console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
};
```

I hope that covers your question

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and give feedback how it goes:

```js
const slideForward = function () {

  if (imageNumber > slideArray.length - 1) {
    imageNumber = -1;
  }
  imageNumber++;
  image.src = `slide-${imageNumber}.PNG`;
  console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
  
};

const slideBack = function () {
  
  if (imageNumber < 0) {
    imageNumber = slideArray.length;
  }
  imageNumber--;
  image.src = `slide-${imageNumber}.PNG`;
  console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't increment or decrement the counter unless it's in the range of your slide array and only add one "keydown" event.

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector("next");
const previousBtn = document.querySelector("previous");
const image = document.getElementById("slideShow");

let imageNumber = 0;

console.log(image.src, imageNumber);

const slideForward = function () {
    if(imageNumber >= 0 && imageNumber < slideArray.length - 1){
    imageNumber++;
    image.src = `slide-${imageNumber}.PNG`; 
}
console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
};

const slideBack = function () {
    if(imageNumber > 0 && imageNumber <= slideArray.length - 1){
        imageNumber--;
        image.src = `slide-${imageNumber}.PNG`;
    }
    console.log(image.src, imageNumber);
};

document.addEventListener("keydown", function (q) {
  if (q.key === "ArrowLeft") {
    slideBack();
  }
  if (q.key === "ArrowRight") {
    slideForward();
  }  
});
```